# How make massban in discord.py?

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots

I used this command, but the bot not ban anyone and does not write an error to the console.

```
@bot.command()
async def massban(ctx):
    for user in ctx.guild.members:
        try:
            await user.ban()
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: It does not write an error to console, because you supressing all the errors. (except: pass)

Comment: @Luuk Nothing help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Fixator also mentioned, you won't be able to see the error as far as you're excepting every error and passing it.

```
@bot.command()
async def massban(ctx):
    for user in ctx.guild.members:
        try:
            await user.ban()
        except Exception as error:
            print(error)
            pass
```

That's how you can catch the error without interrupting the for-loop.

Please also doublecheck the permissions of your bot and the member listing.

Answer (score 0):

*If you sure that bot has a ban perms on server.*

1. Check if bot has enough cache for that operation. For example, send `len(guild.members)` into channel before iterating over members. If it says 1-2, you, most likely, dont have enough [intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html).
2. Bot can't ban users that has roles above bot's top role:
   [image: Bot able to ban user, but not an admin]